# Language which compiles to t-sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dsl

I am writing a lot of t-sql at my job and frequently I wish there would be some type of extensions available (for example something like TypeScript is for Javascript - you can create classes and all this OO stuff and it just compiles to standard Javascript).

A quick example what I would want to have (the semantic should be improved off course):

```
-- Input:
def $t sysname
$t = 'Table1'
select * from $t
-- Output:
select * from Table1

-- Input (issues: remove last comma, newline characters):
def $t sysname
set $t = 'Table1'
;with Units as (select distinct Unit from $t),
[repeat @i; i=1; i<4]S$i as (select Unit, count(*) C from $t where T = $i group by Unit),[endrepeat]
select distinct [repeat (@i; i=1; i<4)]isnull(S$i.C, 0) C$i,[endrepeat]
from Units u
    [repeat @i; i=1; i<4]left join S$i on (u.Unit = S$i.Unit)[endrepeat]
group by [repeat @i; i=1; i<4]S$i.C,[endrepeat]
order by [repeat $i; i=4; i>0]S$i.C desc,[endrepeat]
-- Output:
;with Units as (select distinct Unit from Table1),
S1 as (select Unit, count(*) C from Table1 where T = 1 group by Unit),
S2 as (select Unit, count(*) C from Table1 where T = 2 group by Unit),
S3 as (select Unit, count(*) C from Table1 where T = 3 group by Unit)
select distinct isnull(S1.C, 0) C1, isnull(S2.C, 0) C2, isnull(S3.C, 0) C3
from Units u
    left join S1 on (u.Unit = S1.Unit)
    left join S2 on (u.Unit = S2.Unit)
    left join S3 on (u.Unit = S3.Unit)
group by S1.C, S2.C, S3.C
order by S3.C desc, S2.C desc, S1.C desc

-- Input (sq = singlequotes):
declare @sql varchar(max), @year int
set @year = 2012
set @sql = [sq]
select JobId, InventoryItem
from openquery(MyLinkedServer, '
    select JobId, InventoryItem
    from Jobs
    where year(Created) = {@year}
        and Type <> {TypeA}
') x
[endsq]
exec @sql
-- Output:
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @year int
set @year = 2012
set @sql = '
    select  JobID, InventoryItem
    from    openquery (MyLinkedServer, ''
            select  JobID, InventoryItem
            from    XXX.Jobs
            where   year(Created) = ' + convert(varchar, @year) + '
                    and Type <> ''''TypeA''''
            order by "Created" desc
    '') x
'
exec @sql
```

Looks like I would need to write my own DSL to implement this, but never used it before, so any ideas are more then welcome. Would Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK (VMSDK) be the right choice for this kind of project? How complex would it become? :)

Edit - ORM was suggested, but this would be run from SSMS directly, not from a language like c# or java... I mean, there would be no objects and stuff, just queries. I removed c# tag because it was misleading. The idea is more in the direction of a SSMS plugin.

Comment: What you are looking for is called an ORM. There are plenty of them for .NET and others.

Comment: Wait, what? Isn't this what ORM is for? LINQ & nHibernate are the ones I can vouch for though I prefer the former.

Comment: I think the idea itself is brilliant, I like SQL as a data-centric language but it could be much better by adding some syntactic sugar to it. It's a pity the BQL idea was not developed further

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the BQL Specification fits the bill? (see the link for spec)

> There is CoffeeScript, Dart, Typescript, etc for JavaScript. There is
>   LESS and SCSS for CSS.
>
> Why not something for SQL?
>
> So I played the devil's advocate and said: "What if SQL was a compile
>   target?"
>
> In doing so, I found myself wanting a language that:
>
> - **Strict superset of SQL.** This is important because it promotes a clean
>     transition. One can move migrate their SQL codebase incrementally
>     since all valid SQL is also valid in this language.
> - **Promotes good and efficient SQL practices**
> - **Promotes keeping SQL code DRY**
> - **Transpiles into easily readable SQL**

http://tech.pro/blog/1917/a-better-query-language-bql-language-specification

Comment: https://github.com/lelandrichardson/BQL is the github repo associated with that page (added here in case of link-rot)

Comment: The link in the answer is broken, but here's another one http://www.intelligiblebabble.com/a-better-query-language-bql-language-specification

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at linqpad.you can write a `Linq` query and see the  generated sql

Its not a SSMS plugin but an Application of its own just like SSMS.

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

[image: LinqPad]

Answer (score 2):

Mapping a relational model (SQL) into an object oriented one (C#, C++, Java ... etc) is accomplished using something called an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping). You basically work with OO model and the ORM translates what you're doing to SQL. There are hundreds of them out there, though [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx), [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) are among the better known ones.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you are stating you want to have callouts or code reuse be .  I can offer you a few things that I work with in SQL a lot with.

1. Honestly if you want defined outcomes with different presets I would suggest just creating objects like views, functions and procedures.
2. However if you are stating that this is just stuff day in and day out you want to change for code call outs you can do these in SQL: Template parameters.

.

You then just quickly hit (2005 and below): CTRL + SHIFT + M / (2008 and higher) Alt + Q, then S in succession.

My example to you would be:

```
Select top 10 *
from <tablename, varchar(128), dbo.orders>
```

3. The problem with these is that you then have your whole code changed when you apply them at times so I like a 3rd party tool called Redgate SQL Prompt.  I basically create snippets on the fly for little things that are objects to me and then just have key combos for them.  It is great if you code in SSMS day in and day out IMHO.  You can hover over objects and get their contained types, you can set up formatting to highlight a block of code and then create your own formatting principles of how you like your formatting, the snippets alone make it worth having as they work much faster than the native ones in 2012 and better than hacks like getting AutoHotKey.